# matrix norm and vector norm

Tags: matrices

There is a matrix H and it has $n \times q_n$ dimension. $$\begin{bmatrix} h_{11}&\cdots& h_{1j}&\cdots& h_{1q_n}\\
h_{21}&\cdots& h_{2j}&\cdots& h_{2q_n}\\
\vdots& &\vdots& \ddots& \vdots \\
h_{n1}& \cdots& h_{nj}& \cdots& h_{nq_n}\end{bmatrix}$$

The singular values $\sigma_i$ of matrix H are $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$, where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $H^TH$. 
Is there any relationships between ${\|h_{j}\|_2}^2$ and the singular values $\sigma_i$??? where $h_j$ is one column of matrix H. 
Such as ${\|h_{j}\|_2}^2 \le \sigma_i^2$ or ${\|h_{j}\|_2}^2 \le \lambda_i$

Comment: You have $\sum_j\|h_j\|_2^2 = \sum_i\sigma_i^2$, which is the square of the Frobenius norm of $H$.

Comment: Is there any inequality between ${\|h_{j}\|_2}^2$ and the maximum singular value?

Comment: You can get (a bad) one from the equality: $\|h_k\|_2^2\le\sum_j\|h_j\|_2^2 = \sum_i\sigma_i^2\le\min\{n,q_n\}\sigma_\max^2$. You can replace the min by the rank of H (which is a little better).

Answer (score 1):

**Counterexample:** Take for example
$$
H=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The singular values are $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}$, while the columns of $H$ have $2$-norms $2$ and $\sqrt2$. Notice that $\sqrt2>\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}\approx0.87$.

Comment: Can you teach me how to calculate the singular values of a square matrix?

Comment: You have given the definition in your post, that's it.

Comment: As your example, the eigenvalues are 2 and -1. How can I get the singular values $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}$ ?

Comment: 2 and -1 are the eigenvalues of $H$. They are totally unrelated to the singular values as long as the matrix isn't symmetric. Have a look into your own post where you have defined the singular values.